# compute mfcc for varying time intervals based on time stamps

Tags: python, audio, mfcc, librosa

I came across this nice tutorial https://github.com/manashmndl/DeadSimpleSpeechRecognizer where the data is trained based on samples separated by folders and all mfcc are calculated at once.

I am trying to achieve something similar but in a different way.

Based on this : https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.mfcc.html

librosa can compute mfcc for any audio. as follows :

```
import librosa  
y, sr = librosa.load('test.wav')
mymfcc= librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr =sr)
```

but I want to calculate mfcc for the audio part by part based on timestamps from a file.

the file has labels and timestamps as follows :

```
0.0 2.0 sound1
2.0 4.0 sound2
4.0 7.0 silence
7.0 11.0 sound1
```

I want to calculate mfcc of each range, my hope is to arrive at a labelled train data that looks like   mfcc and its corresponding label. 
mfcc_1 , sound1
mfcc_2, sound2
and so on.

How do I achieve this?

I looked at [generate mfcc's for audio segments based on annotated file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48333516/generate-mfccs-for-audio-segments-based-on-annotated-file)  , and  question is similar but I found both the question and answer somewhat hard to follow (because I'm very new to this field).

TIA

**UPDATE**:  My Code :

```
import librosa
from subprocess import call

def ListDir():
    call(["ls", "-l"])

def main():
    ListDir()
    readfile_return_segmentsmfcc()

my_segments =[]
# reading annotated file
def         readfile_return_segmentsmfcc():

    pat ='000.mp3'
    y, sr = librosa.load(pat)

    print "\n sample rate :"
    print sr

    with open("000.txt", "rb") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            start_time, end_time, label = line.split('\t')
            start_time = float(start_time)
            end_time = float(end_time)
            label = label.strip()
            my_segments.append((start_time, end_time, label))

            start_index = librosa.time_to_samples(start_time)
            end_index = librosa.time_to_samples(end_time)

            required_slice = y[start_index:end_index]
            required_mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=required_slice, sr=sr)
            print "Mfcc size is {} ".format(mfcc.shape)


            print start,end,label


    return my_segments


main()
```

Comment: In my case, I just used `            required_slice = y[start_index[0]:end_index[0]
` didn't have to use the int() conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- read the start and end times:
  `start=2.0`
  `end=4.0`
- convert to samples index using [`librosa.time_to_samples`](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.time_to_samples.html#librosa.core.time_to_samples):
  `start_index = librosa.time_to_samples(start)`
  `end_index = librosa.time_to_samples(end)`
- use python `[:]` operator to get the relevant slice from data:
  `slice = y[int(start_index):int(end_index)]`
- compute mfcc on `slice`, etc.

Comment: Hope it helped - Please, consider accepting my answer. ;)

Comment: thank you for your answer. Please suggest how to store the mfcc's generated in the last step? because the mfcc.shape is (20,X) where X is dependent on the length of a particular segment. so in above example, 4 different mfcc will be generated.

Comment: I get the following error : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_mfcc_based_on_segments.py", line 46, in <module>
    main()
  File "generate_mfcc_based_on_segments.py", line 10, in main
    read_annotate_file_return_segments_and_mfcc()
  File "generate_mfcc_based_on_segments.py", line 33, in read_annotate_file_return_segments_and_mfcc
    required_slice = y[start_index:end_index]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
`

Updated question with my code

Comment: The error is because index should be an integer. I added conversion to int

Comment: your thoughts on whether  a namedtuple should be used ?

Comment: can you kindly please tell how to save these mfcc's that are generated in the last step : `            required_mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=required_slice, sr=sr)
`

Comment: That is on a more broader scope than this question, and highly depends on what is the application and how are you going to use the saved data. If you provide in a new question what you are trying to achieve, and what you have tried - you increase the likelihood to get help :)

Comment: I want to feed the mfcc and the labels to train a neural network.

Comment: @EranW I am working on a very similar project, my question, approach and where I'm stuck is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514322/train-a-neural-network-with-mfcc-using-keras it will be great if you could shed some light. thanks